# PHPMailer send the messages with my server email

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

as written on the subject, PHPMailer send the messages with my server email, not the email of the actual sender.
for example:

from: sendername myservername@server.com

the sender email doesn't show up on the email from section

here is my code

```
$result = mysql_query($insert_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    if($result)
    {


    require_once('../se482/class.phpmailer.php');

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

//$mail->IsSMTP(true); 
$mail = new PHPMailer;                                     // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypassowrd';                           // SMTP password
$mail->Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
 $mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
$mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
//$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); 

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body = $comment;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
  $mail->Send();
  $mail->SmtpClose();
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}

    }
```

Comment: remove the comment on `//$mail->IsSMTP(true); ` to use the smtp you have setup

Comment: if I remove it i get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function IsSMTP() on a non-objec

Comment: put it below `$mail = new PHPMailer; `

Comment: i got this additional error: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: hmmm. i assume your `username` and `password` for gmail is corret?

Comment: Gmail does not allow you to send from arbitrary addresses because it will cause SPF failures. You can set predefined aliases in your gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `class.smtp.php` as well to use `smtp`. Also uncomment `//$mail->isSMTP(true);`

As mentioned in documentation to avoid this you can include only autoloader class that is `PHPMailerAutoload.php`

updated code

```
$result = mysql_query($insert_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    if($result)
    {


    //require_once('../se482/class.phpmailer.php');
    // require_once('../se482/class.smtp.php');
//or
  require_once('../se482/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP(true); 
$mail = new PHPMailer;                                     // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypassowrd';                           // SMTP password
$mail->Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
 $mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
$mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
//$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); 

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body = $comment;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
  $mail->Send();
  $mail->SmtpClose();
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}

    }
```

**Update**

You have also add your `app` credential in `get_auth_token.php` as mentioned in documentation for use gmail. Here is link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2

Comment: sorry, how can i include the class and use smtp?

Comment: still got the same error: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Comment: are you using `PHPMailerAutoload.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

`$mail->from` is set to `$email` which isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: no its defined but i did not copy the whole code here